# pop-up ads appear even when using ad block

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8.1, popups, adblock

I am using ABP ad-block extension of google chrome on my windows 8.1 laptop. But it doesn't work. Useless pop-ups appear out of no-where. Even if I click anywhere on the screen these pop-up ads appear.The ad blocker shows how many ads it has blocked but doesn't prevent these pop-ups from appearing. I want to know the possible reasons behind this or is there some problem with the browser and ad-block compatibility? Because I am using the same ad-blocker extension on chrome browser in my macbook air.

Thanx in advance!!

Comment: Well the question addressed above happens to answer how can I get rid of the problem that I was facing..but it doesn't address why I might be facing this problem(which by the way is my problem)..so I don't think its  a possible duplicate..

Comment: You have the problem because you have some malware (we don't know which because there isn't enough information in your question). ABP blocks ordinary popups not those from malware.

Answer (score 1):

Advertisements that show up even if an adblocker is present, means only one thing. Your pc has been infected with malware/spyware.

Run a check with hitman pro or malware bytes and see how bad it is. If the infection is huge, be ready to reinstall windows, because it is likely that you won't be cleaning everything up and a reinfection within a month time is likely to occur.

Answer (score 1):

This will help you block ads Its what I use on my **Macbook Pro**. **Windows** and **Linux OS**.

This along with Adblock will kill all Pop ups.

First go to the hosts file.

**Located here**:

On Windows, the file is usually at `%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\.` (Copy that path, press Win+R, paste that path, and hit Enter.)

The Host file looks like the text below. May vary depending on programs you've installed.

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 my-real-hostname
::1 my-ipv6-addr
```

You can Grab a Pre add blocked filled host file [Here](http://www.hosts-file.net/)

Props go to [LifeHacker](http://lifehacker.com/5817447/how-to-block-unwanted-ads-in-all-applications-and-speed-up-web-browsing-with-the-hosts-file)

Where you can read more about this method as well as how to do it in other Operating systems.